# wso2 bps support Chinese character in variables

Tags: wso2

I am working on bps 3.2.0. When I send request to bps server, if there are any Chinese character in variables (request body) , it will be converted to ??? in bps. I would like to know how can I fix it?
Does it cause by any running parameters which I should take care?
Or does it caused by java web application iso8859-1 bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is caused by uni code setting when starting wso2 application, just add
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dfile.encoding=utf8